# How to force Waffle authentication to use Kerberos only?

Tags: java, spring, waffle

I have this code that implements Waffle negotiate authentication in a Java Spring application.

Negotiate uses both Kerberos and NTLM.

How can I configure waffle to use Kerberos only (without NTLM)?

This is the code for SecurityConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
    @Autowired
    private NegotiateSecurityFilter negotiateSecurityFilter;

    @Autowired
    private NegotiateSecurityFilterEntryPoint entryPoint; 

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {  

          http
          .csrf().disable()
          .authorizeRequests()
          .anyRequest()
          .authenticated()
          .and()
          .httpBasic().disable()
          .addFilterBefore(negotiateSecurityFilter, BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)  
          .exceptionHandling()
          .authenticationEntryPoint(entryPoint)
          .and()
          .headers()
          .addHeaderWriter(new StaticHeadersWriter("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")); 

         http.cors();
                
    }
}
```

And in WaffleConfig.java are the waffle security filters as follows.

```
@Configuration
public class WaffleConfig {
    
    @Bean
    public WindowsAuthProviderImpl waffleWindowsAuthProvider() {
        return new WindowsAuthProviderImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    public NegotiateSecurityFilterProvider negotiateSecurityFilterProvider(
            WindowsAuthProviderImpl windowsAuthProvider) {
        return new NegotiateSecurityFilterProvider(windowsAuthProvider);
    }

    @Bean
    public BasicSecurityFilterProvider basicSecurityFilterProvider(
            WindowsAuthProviderImpl windowsAuthProvider) {
        return new BasicSecurityFilterProvider(windowsAuthProvider);
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterProviderCollection waffleSecurityFilterProviderCollection(
            NegotiateSecurityFilterProvider negotiateSecurityFilterProvider,
            BasicSecurityFilterProvider basicSecurityFilterProvider) {
        SecurityFilterProvider[] securityFilterProviders =
                {negotiateSecurityFilterProvider, basicSecurityFilterProvider};
        return new SecurityFilterProviderCollection(securityFilterProviders);
    }

    @Bean
    public NegotiateSecurityFilterEntryPoint negotiateSecurityFilterEntryPoint(
            SecurityFilterProviderCollection securityFilterProviderCollection) {
        NegotiateSecurityFilterEntryPoint negotiateSecurityFilterEntryPoint =
                new NegotiateSecurityFilterEntryPoint();
        negotiateSecurityFilterEntryPoint.setProvider(securityFilterProviderCollection);
        return negotiateSecurityFilterEntryPoint;
    }

    @Bean
    public NegotiateSecurityFilter waffleNegotiateSecurityFilter(
            SecurityFilterProviderCollection securityFilterProviderCollection) {
        NegotiateSecurityFilter negotiateSecurityFilter = new NegotiateSecurityFilter();
        negotiateSecurityFilter.setProvider(securityFilterProviderCollection);
        return negotiateSecurityFilter;
    }

    // This is required for Spring Boot so it does not register the same filter twice
    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean waffleNegotiateSecurityFilterRegistration(
            NegotiateSecurityFilter waffleNegotiateSecurityFilter) {
        FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
        registrationBean.setFilter(waffleNegotiateSecurityFilter);
        registrationBean.setEnabled(false);
        return registrationBean;
    }

}
```